# making two input fields editable with a button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have got two input fields which i would like to make editable with a button click.

The data of these two fields is to be written to database in two separate columns which can be achieved by ajax.

But i would like to know about the first part. Tried to google a lot but didnt found a viable solution :(

Comment: Unless the input fields are disabled they are editable, so I'm guessing that's not what you're talking about. Please post some code and ask a specific question. This is not enough to work with.

Comment: does the input field currently have `readonly="readonly"` or `disabled="disabled"` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/urixoh/edit#javascript,html,live)*

html:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
<button class="toggle_input_state">enable / disable</button>
```

**This allows you to toggle your states:**

```
$('button.toggle_input_state').on('click',function(){
   var $el = $(this).prev('input');
   $el.prop("disabled",!$el.prop("disabled"));
});
```

You can use `.prop()` since jQuery 1.6.

Answer (score 4):

Change the disabled property on the textbox.

HTML:

```
<input id="i1" type="textbox" class="myInput" disabled="true" />
<input id="i2" type="textbox" class="myInput" disabled="true" />
<button id="i3"></button>
​
```

Javascript:

```
$("#i3").click(function(){
    $(".myInput").prop("disabled",false);
});​
```

Comment: +1 Damn, you beat me to it :)

Comment: You could use the readonly attribute instead of disabled, too, and it will behave slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
   $('#inputid').attr("disabled","disabled");
   $("#inputid").removeAttr('disabled');
```

like

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
    $("#inputid").removeAttr('disabled');
});​
```